# Ask re-run test failed and merge (RobotFramework)

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have 3 test suites: `test1.robot` (10 TCs inside), `test2.robot`(3 TCs inside), `test3.robot`(2TCs inside).

I run all test suites by shell script: `robot --variable:ABC --name Testing --outputdir /perf-logs/Testing test1.robot test2.robot test3.robot`

I found that we have 2 ways to rerun:
`--rerunfailed` (for tests) and `--rerunfailedsuites` (for testsuites)

I have some question:

1/ What is different between them (`--rerunfailed` vs `--retunfailedsuites`)

2/ Assumpting I have 2 TCs failed in test suite (`test1.robot`) and 1 TCs failed in testsuite `test2.robot`, so Which re-run I should use?

3/ Assumpting first time run 3 testsuites I have 1 `output.xml`. After re-running TCs failed (for 2 testsuites) I have another `output2.xml`. Could I merge them?

4/ In case I only re-run 1 TCs failed (in `test1.robot`) and get result in `output3.xml`. Could I merge `output3.xml` with `first output.xml`?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Difference:

https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html

```
-R, --rerunfailed <file>
    Selects failed tests from an earlier output file to be re-executed.
-S, --rerunfailedsuites <file>
    Selects failed test suites from an earlier output file to be re-executed.
```

2. Which to use:

   if you want to rerun an entire suite use rerunfailedsuite if you want to rerun failed test cases only not the passed tests in the suite then use rerunfailed ( if test are independent)
3. to combine files

   rebot --outputdir . --output final_output.xml output.xml output.xml

4)same as above